# Hide a specific div in mobile view only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have HTML/CSS content working in aspx page.

I want a specific div section (comprising some css classes) to hide when switched to mobile view.

I have tried using the following:

Set bootstrap property to:

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px){}
```

and setting CSS/class property to:

```
  {visibility: hidden;}
```

But when tested the code, it hid the div permanently.

Code Bootstrap:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 768px)



   .col-md-7 {
      width: 58.33333333%;
    }

   .service {
      background: #005366;
      color: #999;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
   }

   .service h4 a{
      color: #fff;
   }

   .service img {
      float: right;
      margin-left: 10px;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.1s;
      -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.1s;
      -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.1s;
      -o-transition: all 0.3s ease 0.1s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease 0.1s;
    }

   .service img:hover {
      opacity: .9;
    }

   .service-in {
      padding: 15px 0 0 10px;
      min-height: 150px;
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which class / element are you trying to hide?  Have you tried display: none instead of visibility: hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you have pasted does not show the exact css where you have made it hidden. Show us the code that looks like below (or use the code below)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   .yourClassName {
      visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

or alternatively,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
   .yourClassName {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

Your div is getting permanently hidden means the media query might not have been applied correctly.

Help us to help you.
Welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your mediaquery doesn't have start and end. Use brackets `{}`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

       .yourclass {
          //your styles
       }
}
```